# google chrome extensions content script and background

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an google chrome extension. when the user clicks the browser action icon it is suppose to "snow" on the current webpage. I have the javascript but can't figure out how to use content script or background script. how can I inject my javascript snow.js and the snow.html file

```
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot inject HTML file to the Web page with the content script feature. That is, JavaScript and CSS are available as the content script. If you want to put the new canvas tag to the Web site, you need to create the tag with your JavaScript code. In this case, its script will become the snow.js by like the following code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
body.appendChild(canvas);
```

When injecting your script against the current tab, you need to define the permission in your manifest.json file:

```
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

And, you register the click event handler for your browserAction button. In the handler function, you can inject your JavaScript file into the current tab.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: "snow.js"
  });
});
```

You will see the falling snow in the tab, if succeeded...

Comment: Thanks so much! just another question: it works perfectly fine on site like google start page but not on website with extensive backgrounds (like nytimes.com) . What can I do so that the snow falls "in front" of the sites elements and is thus always visible ?

Comment: Does the layer displaying the snow have z-index value of css? I think that it is a problem regarding CSS.